# How can I make a clickable dropdown menu that works with mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a small website and through using a tutorial ([link](http://designshack.net/articles/css/verticalaccordionav/)) I created a menu that when hovered over is revealing submenu's hidden under it. I have an average knowledge in HTML and CSS but never done any scripting myself.

How would I go about making it toggle on click instead of hovering so it can be browsed on mobile phones and tablets properly which is its planned use?

### Code

The following code is also available as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c768Q/).

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <nav>
   <div class="menu-item alpha">
      <h4><a href="#">Sida 1</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sida 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <h4><a href="#">Sida 2</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <h4><a href="#">Sida 3</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
nav {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 50px auto; /*for display only*/
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.menu-item {
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px; 
}
/*Menu Header Styles*/
.menu-item h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  background: #a90329;
}
.menu-item h4 a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
}
/*Menu Header Styles*/
.menu-item h4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 7px 12px;

  /*Gradient*/
  background: #a90329; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%, #8f0222 44%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a90329), color-stop(44%,#8f0222), color-stop(100%,#6d0019)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.menu-item h4:hover{  
  background: #cc002c; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cc002c 0%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cc002c), color-stop(100%,#6d0019)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #cc002c 0%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc002c', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
*First Item Styles*/
.alpha p {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    color:#F00 ;
}/*ul Styles*/
.menu-item ul {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu-item ul a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

/*li Styles*/
.menu-item li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.menu-item li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
/*ul Styles*/
.menu-item ul {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 0px; /*Collapses the menu*/
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*ul Styles*/
.menu-item ul {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;

  /*Animation*/
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
       -o-transition: height 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
          transition: height 1s ease;
}


.menu-item:hover ul {
height: 93px;}
```

Comment: U require JS Onclick function  i think...please set it up in fiddle as @BeNdErR  suggested..

Comment: @Rashie100: Do you want a HTML / CSS only solution or is it ok to use JavaScript?

Comment: Already got this part of my site working, no need to worry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using CSS, although you'll have to change your markup a little. You can get the effect you are looking for using checkboxes and labels, along with the adjacent sibling CSS selector:

**HTML**

```
<input id="sida1" type="checkbox">
<div class="menu-item alpha">
    <label for="sida1"><a>Sida 1</a></label>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sida 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sida 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox]{display:none}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .menu-item ul {
    height: 93px;
}
```

I've swapped your `<h4>`s out with labels and displayed them as blocks. I've also removed the `href` attribute for each header's link, as it hashes the URL and prevents the checkbox ever getting checked.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c768Q/6/)

Comment: @Rashie100 Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c768Q/44/).

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $( ".menu-item" ).each(function() {
        $( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {
          $( "ul",this).slideToggle(75);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to help if you set up the working code on jsfiddle but to answer your question, you could use simple [javascript](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle the class onClick. The class will do what it currently does on hover to show submenu.

You can also use a css library which would have [dropdows](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns), [navs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav), etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/c768Q/21/ is the working demo js fiddle for what you asked for. Something like this,

`$( ".menu-item" ).click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").toggleClass("add-height");
});`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the route chosen by using the pseudo-property :hover as a selector to animate the transition leaves us very little room to work with. They are usually used to style a link, but can be applied to other elements (in this case, ul) - but using the other selectors available doesn't give us the desired effect.
I would suggest using Javascript or a library like jQuery, which simplifies a lot of animation operations.
See this example as a replacement, which does exactly what you want: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

When starting out fresh with a new site today I would also consider a modern template like Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com), which starts you out with clean code using the newest technology while providing backwards-compatibility, sparing you a lot of possible frustration debugging in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Accordion Jquery Plugins, there a lot of it.
One Example is : [bassistance](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/)

But you could change the example from designshack into click, I just modified it. 
You can check at : [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danzkusuma/2fTnH/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu-item').click(function(){
        var uls = $(this).find("ul");
        $('.menu-item').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('.menu-item').find("ul").slideUp(200, function(){
            uls.slideDown(500);
        });   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jQuery.

[Here is demo for it](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bGdIj/)